# Generate barcode based on numbers like "1100000001"

Tags: ios, barcode

I am doing a project which can auto generated a barcode through my iphone application. 
I happened to find this https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes which i think would be a great help to me.

However, nothing happened when i use it. 
These are the steps i have done:

1) Open my own iphone application and import all the .h and .m files.
2) After which, i type this into my barcode.m (this is the xib showing the auto generated barcode)

```
#import "UIImage-NKDBarcode.h"
#import "NKDCode39Barcode.h"
-(void)showBarcode {
NKDBarcode * nkdbarcode = [[NKDCode39Barcode alloc] initWithContent:@"1234567890123"];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageFromBarcode:nkdbarcode];
// assume barcodeIV is an outlet to an imageview
[barcodeIV setImage:image];
}
```

But it did not work. Did i miss anything or did something wrong? 
Sincerely hope that anyone can help me out :)

Thanks&Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I used the same library with out any issues.
Steps what i have done is

```
1.dowload https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes
2.add the complete file named "netshade-Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes-d0aabd0" to the project folder.
3.Import like #import "BarcodeManager.h" in your viewControllers .h file
4.Add the following code where yo want to generate bar code with an input given
```

**Code:**

```
UIImage *barcodeImg=[BarcodeManager
   generateBarcodeImageWithContent:@"123" type:Code39 size:CGSizeMake(0,
   0)];
           imgView.image=barcodeImg;
```

i hope this will help you dude..:)

Comment: I don't see a BarcodeManager.h in the project.  Where did you get that?